# Display remote api json data into google maps

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, google-maps

I'm trying to display remote api json into google maps. The current
code works with localjson that resides in the same script, however I
would like to populate the google map with remote api json. I'm using Angularjs google maps integration. The code work perfect when referencing json that is in the same script as the google maps implementation. But now I would like to populate the google maps with json from another source(remote json) other than local.
Please advise. Please see my code below for more information
I have tried calling the testData in the for loop but I'm getting an error:
"testData is not defined" but from my understading it is defined at the top of my script "points.testData = [];

---

```
  var points = this;
  points.testData = [];

  $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://api.jsonbin.io/b/61361f26dfe0cf16eb55fd9f',
  })

  .then(function successCallback(response) {
        console.log("success, ",response);
        $scope.testData = response.data;

    }, function errorCallback(response) {
      console.log("failure, ",response);.
    });


  // GOOGLE MAPS CODE
  $scope.highlighters = [];
  $scope.gMap = null;

  var winInfo = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

  var googleMapOption = {
    zoom: 2,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(2.8, -187.3),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
  };


  $scope.gMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googleMap'), googleMapOption);

  var createHighlighter = function(citi) {

    var citiesInfo = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: $scope.gMap,
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(citi.attributes.coordinates.lat, citi.attributes.coordinates.lng),
      title: citi.attributes.name
    });

    citiesInfo.content = '<div>' + citi.attributes.address1 + '</div>' +
    '<div>' + citi.attributes.openingHours + '</div>';

    google.maps.event.addListener(citiesInfo, 'click', function() {
      winInfo.setContent('<h1>' + citiesInfo.title + '</h1>' + citiesInfo.content);
      winInfo.open($scope.gMap, citiesInfo);
    });
    $scope.highlighters.push(citiesInfo);
  };

  for (var i = 0; i < testData.length; i++) {
    createHighlighter(testData[i]);
  }
```

This is my json file

```
var cities = [{
          "attributes": {
              "name": "Test1",
              "city": "Mthatha",
              "address1": "Cnr Sisson and Sutherland Road",
              "coordinates": {
                  "lng": 28.7648433,
                  "lat": -31.5805384
              },
              "openingHours": "Mon-Fri: 8am-6pm, Sat-Sun: 8am-5pm"
          },
             "attributes": {
              "name": "Test2",
              "city": "Mthatha",
              "address1": "Cnr Sisson and Sutherland Road",
              "coordinates": {
                  "lng": 28.7648433,
                  "lat": -31.5805384
              },
              "openingHours": "Mon-Fri: 8am-6pm, Sat-Sun: 8am-5pm"
          }];
```

Comment: And what have you tried / what didn't work? Please read [ask]. Your question is too vague and needs details.

Comment: I have tried calling the testData in the for loop in order to loop through my json data but I'm getting an error: "testData is not defined" but from my understading it is defined at the top of my script "points.testData = []; So I want to pull testData from an external json but its not working

Comment: "its not working" is not a proper problem description. **What** is not working? If loading the file from an external URL fails, then you should debug / check your browser's javascript console for related errors, etc. and provide this along with your question. Right now, the URL in the code you shared is local (`url: 'data/data.json'`). Please update your question.

Comment: I've updated the URL. I'm able to get back the results from remote json on the console.
I would like to display the remote data into google maps but I'm getting the error on the console(testData is not defined) and that error is coming from the forLoop in my code. I'm not sure what I'm missing here.

GoogleMaps is working fine though with local json but I'm uanble to get it to work when pulling from external url.

Comment: What happens if you try to `console.log(testData)` just before the `for` loop? You are adding the API response to `$scope.testData`.

Comment: Looks like a problem with asynchronous data not being available until after it is needed.  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had to move the for loop inside the .thenFunction() and the issue is resolved.

Thanks for all your comments.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.